# Sort function not sorting! JAVA

Tags: java

Below are chunks of my code from my quiz program in Java. I am trying to read/write high scores to a file and sort the high score table.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        sort(highscoreTable);
        int score1 = 0;
        int score2 = 0;
        int totalscore = 0;
        int NumberofQuestions = 5;

        // RECORDS TO STORE QUESTION, ANSWER WOULD BE HERE //

private static void start(int NumberofQuestions, String[] Answers, String[][] questions, int score1, int score2, int totalscore) throws IOException {
        // DISPLAYED ON THE HOME SCREEN SO USER CAN CHOOSE WHAT THEY WANT TO DO
        System.out.println("[0] Leave\n");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("[1] Play");
            System.out.println("[2] Highscore");
            System.out.print("Enter Choice: ");
            String useranswer = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            if (useranswer.equals("1")) {
                mainLoop(NumberofQuestions, Answers, questions, score1, score2, totalscore);
            } else if (useranswer.equals("2")) {
                sort(highscoreTable);
            } else if (useranswer.equals("0")) {
                try {
                    save();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted this bit to be displayed on the screen first, if the user presses 2, i wanted to program to read from the file and show the preious high scores

```
 public static void save() throws IOException {

        String aggFileName = "agg-"+String.valueOf("06.txt");
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(aggFileName);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : highscoreTable.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); //this statement prints out my keys and values
            out.write(entry.getKey() + "--" + entry.getValue() + "\n");
            System.out.println("Done");
            out.flush();   // Flush the buffer and write all changes to the disk
        }

        out.close();    // Close the file
    }
```

The save method works perfectly and I have no problem with it.

```
public static void mainLoop(int NumberofQuestions, String[]Answers, String[][] questions, int score1, int score2, int totalscore) throws IOException {

// USER WOULD ANSWER QUESTIONS HERE
        addHighscore(name, totalscore);
    }

public static void addHighscore(String name, int totalscore) throws IOException {
        highscoreTable.put(String.valueOf(totalscore), name);
    }
```

The function here adds the users name and total score to a treemap

```
public static void highscoreImport(HashMap highscoreTable) throws IOException {

        String filePath = "agg-06.txt";
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] parts = line.split("--", 2);
            if (parts.length >= 2)
            {
                String key = parts[0];
                String value = parts[1];
                highscoreTable.put(key, value);
            } else {
            }
        }
        for (Object key : highscoreTable.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(key + "--" + highscoreTable.get(key));
        }

        reader.close();

    }
```

This is the part I'm having issues with. I want the program to get the information from the file, and now merge it with the data that is coming from the users recent quiz, and then sort the scores (I want a high score table) so that when the users types "2" to see the high score table, it will be in descending order

```
public static void sort(HashMap highscoreTable) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
        Set set = highscoreTable.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
            System.out.println(me.getValue());
        }
        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(highscoreTable);
        System.out.println("After Sorting:");
        Set set2 = map.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
        while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
            System.out.print(me2.getKey() + ": ");
            System.out.println(me2.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Here, the list outputted "before" and "after" sorting is the same unsorted list

---

Sorry for the long read, I would appreciate any help or pointers in fixing this.

Comment: *This is the part I'm having issues with.* What issues are you having? Errors? (We can't see line numbers in stack overflow) Not sorting? Also, `sort(highscoreTable);` If `highscoreTable` is an array, (you don't show it, please do) then it has to be `Arrays.sort(highscoreTable)` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, please refer to this and try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58986274/edit) your post. Help us understand better so that we can help you.

Comment: Note: you ask about sorting, yet most of your code isn't related to that. So please read [mcve] completely, and repeatly. And your edit doesn't any data?!

Answer (score 0):

Since in the `addHighscore` method you are doing:

```
highscoreTable.put(String.valueOf(totalscore), name);
```

I assume it is a `Map<String, String>` (both key and value types are `String`).

But in the `sort` method you do...

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(highscoreTable);
```

If the types of `highscoreTable` are correctly defined, the `TreeMap` instantiation should fail at compiling time. If not, and as the constructor `TreeMap(Map)` gets ordered by the natural order of its keys (see Javadoc), it is probably ordering it by `String` order or other. So "111" will be before "12" and other unexpected results. It is a good practice to define the types in all the collections and other generic type classes.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is with the type of the score. You are inserting the score as a string. A second minor issue is the sort order should be reversed.

Look at the following example:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("String scores:");
    HashMap<String, String> scores = new HashMap<>();
    scores.put("12", "John");
    scores.put("240", "Mary");
    scores.put("14", "Sean");
    scores.put("35", "Pat");

    sort(scores);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Integer scores:");
    HashMap<Integer,String> integerScores = new HashMap<>();
    integerScores.put(12, "John");
    integerScores.put(240, "Mary");
    integerScores.put(14, "Sean");
    integerScores.put(35, "Pat");

    sort(integerScores);
}

public static void sort(HashMap highscoreTable) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
    Set set = highscoreTable.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
        System.out.println(me.getValue());
    }
    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());    // Descending
    map.putAll(highscoreTable);
    System.out.println("After Sorting:");
    Set set2 = map.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
    while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
        System.out.print(me2.getKey() + ": ");
        System.out.println(me2.getValue());
    }
}
```

}

This example uses your sort method on 'scores', and 'integerScores'. 
Here is the sorted output:
String scores:
35: Pat
240: Mary
14: Sean
12: John

Integer scores:
240: Mary
35: Pat
14: Sean
12: John

You can see in the first sort that 35 comes before 240, because 3 comes before 2. It is doing a string sort. The second sort is by the value of an integer. Once you understand this, it is easy to fix your code.

The original code inserts the key as a String:

```
highscoreTable.put(key, value);
```

The key should be an Integer:

```
highscoreTable.put(Integer.valueOf(key), value);
```

Also note that the provided answer can be easily run. It includes data (which is simpler that attaching a file), and output. When questions are formatted this way, it is easier to get help.